# Bash passing array as reference to function gets clobbered

Tags: bash

I am using GNU bash version 4.4.12 and coming across an unusual situation. I am trying to pass an array by reference to a function. So the following code works as expected.

```
function test() {
    local -n varK=${2}
    local varJ=$(( ${1} + 10 ))
    echo "${varJ}, ${varK[@]}"
}
varI=( 1 2 )
varJ=3
echo "result = '$( test 1 varI )'"  # result = '11, 1 2'
echo "varI = '${varI[@]}'"          # varI = '1 2'
echo "varJ = '${varJ}'"             # varJ = '3'
```

The weird situation is that if I use the variable `varI` within the function, even if I define it as a local variable, then the variable `varI` gets clobbered.

```
function test() (
    local -n varK=${2}
    local varI=$(( ${1} + 10 ))
    echo "${varI}, ${varK[@]}"
)
varI=( 1 2 )
varJ=3
echo "result = '$( test 1 varI )'"  # result = '11, 11'
echo "varI = '${varI[@]}'"          # varI = '1 2'
echo "varJ = '${varJ}'"             # varJ = '3'
```

Does not the command `local -n varK=${2}` make a local copy of the array passed by reference?  Also, if I am running the function in a subshell (and calling it as a subshell, should it not affect the parent process as all the documents claim?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order to use `varI` within my function and still have access to referenced array, I made a local copy of the reference array:

```
local varJ=( "${varK[@]}" )
```

Answer (score 0):

The nameref doesn't know anything about the name it refers to; it is a simple alias. `local -n varK=varI` simply states that whenever you use the parameter name `varK`, pretend it is really `varI`, whatever that name means. By the time you use `varK`, `varI` is a local variable with the value 11, so that's what `varK` is as well. (Part of the confusion may also lie in how `bash` treats a non-array name used with array syntax; `${varI[@]}` and `${varI}` are equivalent whether or not the array attribute is set on the name.)